# UIView rotated 90 degrees when added to landscape view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I'm working on a custom `UIPopoverController`. I'm not subclassing, I'm writing my own from scratch as a `NSObject` subclass.

It works quite simply. It adds a fullscreen `UIView` to the `UIWindow` to intercept touches. Above that view, it adds the (smaller) popover view and it positions the popover at a suitable point.

I've tested it in a portraid iPad app and it works fine. It positions the popover view well.

But now I've encountered a problem. I need to use it in a landscape iPad app, but the view of my popover controller is still displayed portrait rather than landscape. It doesn't autorotate (which, I thought, it should).

I know I can manually rotate the view by setting the transform property. But this will make things really complex, because I will have to recalculate the correct positioning, taking the 90 degree rotation in account. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a look at what the *UIPopoverController* is doing here. From the documentation:

> If the user rotates the device while a popover is visible, the popover
>   controller hides the popover and then shows it again at the end of the
>   rotation. The popover controller attempts to position the popover
>   appropriately for you but you may have to present it again or hide it
>   altogether in some cases.

So the *UIPopoverController* isn't rotating the popover view that it maintains, like a *UIViewController* would. This makes sense, considering that *UIPopoverController* inherits from *NSObject*, and therefore doesn't inherit the *UIViewController*'s code that handles the rotation.

You're trying to implement your own *UIPopoverController* (I won't ask why!), and you're also inheriting from *NSObject*, so you inherit no code that will rotate your views for you. When you add your fullscreen *UIView* to the *UIWindow*, the *UIView* exists within the *UIWindow* coordinate space. When you rotate the device, the coordinate space of the *UIWindow* **never changes**. In order for your view to be rotated and moved to the correct space in landscape mode, you'll have to do this manually by applying a *CGSAffineTransform* to the *transform* property of your *UIView*, perhaps calculating a rotation matrix using an angle derived from the interface orientation of the status bar (this is the sort of thing that a *UIViewController* would do for you!)

Your custom *UIPopoverController* could manage the rotation, but it would be easier to get this for free using a *UIViewController* subclass if possible.

Comment: Right. I forgot to mention one thing, which is that I _am_ using a `UIViewController`. My custom `UIPopoverController` creates a `UIViewController` and adds the view of that view controller as a subview to the current window. I thought too, that this would give me the correct rotation behavior, but it doesn't. Also, when I add this view to a view _already_ in the view hierarchy, it DOES display correctly in landscape. When I add it to the window, it doesn't.

Comment: Why not inherit from `UIViewController` in your custom popover controller?